# Rails 4: can't update current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to update some specific values for current_user but I have had no luck with it. The values do not save and the page doesn't get redirected anywhere whatsoever. Here's the code for user controller in update

```
def update

    @user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, notice: 'Update unsuccessful' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :weight, :height, :age, :activity_level, :goal, :calorie_goal, :fat_goal, :carb_goal, :protein_goal, :fiber_goal, :sugar_goal)
    end
```

I tried to use params[:user] or params[:current_user] instead of user_params but with no luck.. here's html

```
<h2>Set Up Your Profile</h2>

<% @user = current_user %>

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  current user is <%= current_user.username %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :weight %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :weight %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :height %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :height %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :age %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :age %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :activity_level %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :activity_level %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :goal %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :goal %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

here I tried form_for(current_user) as well but didn't work, too... Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: Few questions - are you using devise? where is the `user_params` method? have you tried this in the console? might be worth checking the logs - copy parameters hash and chuck it into `User.find(1).update_attributes(copied_params)`. See if that returns true/false, and check the errors with `user.errors`. Though the fix might be simple, it would be better to spend your time learning how to debug these issues in the future. They happen a lot when you first get started ;)

Comment: Oh I found my error, and it was stupid.. Initially I created a database of people without email. Then I added a column email not null and was trying to update a previously created user whose email was null and it basically didnt allow the update.